# Pythonic way of switching nested dictionary keys with nested values

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

In short I'm working with a nested dictionary structured like this:

```
nested_dict = {'key1':{'nestedkey1': 'nestedvalue1'}}
```

I'm trying to find a pythonic way of switching the keys with the nested values, so it would look like this:

```
nested_dict = {'nestedvalue1':{'nestedkey1': 'key1'}}
```

I'm also trying to rename the nested key values, so ultimately the dictionary would look like this:

```
nested_dict = {'nestedvalue1':{'NEWnestedkey1': 'key1'}}
```

This is closer to what I'm working with:

```
original_dict = {
    'buford': {'id': 1},
    'henley': {'id': 2},
    'emi': {'id': 3},
    'bronc': {'id': 4}
}
```

I want it to look like this:

```
new_dict = {
    1: {'pet': 'buford'},
    2: {'pet': 'henley'},
    3: {'pet': 'emi'},
    4: {'pet': 'bronc'}
}
```

Is there a way to do this in one line using a dictionary comprehension? I'm trying to get the very basics here and avoid having to use things like itertools.

Comment: That's a lot of restrictions.  Just a note, one-liners are not particularly better.

Comment: A weird set of resitrictions, you don't want to use something like "itertools", but a dictionary comprehension is OK? Itertools should always be your first thought. Putting everything on one line isn't something that you should strive for generally.

Comment: I'm new to python so just trying to get a handle of how dictionary comprehensions work with nested dicts. So seeing the structure laid out like it is below is super helpful for me, but I get that using itertools might be more efficient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a dictionary comprehension to achieve this, 'swapping' things round as you build it:

```
new_dict = {v['id']: {'pet': k} for k, v in original_dict.items()}
```

To expand it to a for loop, it'd look something like:

```
new_dict = {}
for k, v in original_dict.items():
  new_dict[v['id']] = {'pet': k}
```

Note that both cases obviously rely on the `'id'` value being unique, or the key will be overwritten for each occurrence.

Comment: this is great, exactly what I was looking for. thanks for your help!

Comment: I think this is the right answer, but the it all really depends on the data that you have. I'd also argue that when you're getting into a nested dict like this, it might be more pythonic to pull it out into a for loop for clarity.

Comment: Could you show me what this would look like with a for loop?

Comment: awesome, thanks again! this makes learning/absorbing a lot smoother for me

Answer (score 0):

For a more generic solution, you can try this:

```
def replace(d, change_to = 'pet'):
  return {b.values()[0]:{change_to:a} for a, b in d.items()}
```

Output:

```
{1: {'pet': 'buford'}, 2: {'pet': 'henley'}, 3: {'pet': 'emi'}, 4: {'pet': 'bronc'}}
```

Comment: Bear in mind that since dictionaries are unordered, using an index on `values()` doesn't guarantee you will get the same item each time (if you have more than one of them).